# cypher delete all node relations where relations count is bigger than a number

Tags: cypher

What's wrong with my cypher. Full description is in the title.

```
match (p:P)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) 
with r, count(r) as num 
where num > 100 
delete r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aggregate for `r` when counting `r`, which means that each row will have a count of exactly 1.

To fix this, you should aggregate for `p`:

```
match (p:P)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) 
with p, count(r) as num 
where num > 100 
match (p)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) 
delete r
```

Another option is to [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) the relationships to a list and [`unwind`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/clauses/unwind/) it for the selected ones:

```
match (p:P)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) 
with p, count(r) as num, collect(r) as rs
where num > 100 
unwind rs as r
delete r
```

If you use this approach, you might as well omit `count(r)` and check the size of the `rs` collection:

```
match (p:P)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) 
with p, collect(r) as rs
where size(rs) > 100 
unwind rs as r
delete r
```

Comment: But If I do it that way , variable r is not defined anymore

Comment: You're right. To work around this, use another `match` - I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Still no result. Running following query after "match (p:P)<-[r:LINK]-(:G) return p, count(r) as num order by num desc limit (25)" still returns results with count over 1000

Comment: What's the result of running the delete query? Did you commit the transaction?

Comment: First query run without any change and results. I tried 3rd query and it was just fine.

Comment: Aha, found the problem. it was a typo. first query is also fine.